# Add index on table owned by other user in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two user & schemas,

1. stage owned by stage user.
2. DataMart owned by DataMart user.

**I want this to happen:**

1. Any new table created in stage should have S/I/U/D access to DataMart user.
   -- I have granted it as

   GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA stage TO datamart;

   but newly added tables does not show any grants to DataMart user.
2. While connected to database with DataMart user, I want to add index on tables in stage database. (which are owned by stage user).

Comment: You also need to alter the default privileges: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to automatically grant the privileges in the stage schema to the DataMart role you have to [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) for the schema. But rather than to assign all privileges you should assign specific privileges, just to be on the safe side (i.e. do not grant TRUNCATE to just any user):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA stage
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
  ON TABLES TO datamart;
```

You have to do the same for sequences, functions and types, if any of the tables in the schema use them.

2. You can't do this. Only a superuser or the table owner can create an index on a table.